# Solve a system of non-linear equations of Iranian Math Competition

Tags: systems-of-equations, contest-math, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to find all positive integers $a,b$ and $c$ that satisfy these conditions:
\begin{cases}
a^3 - b^3 - c^3 = 3abc \\
a^2 = 2(b+c)
\end{cases}

When I saw that I remember this algebraic alliance: $$(a-b-c)(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+ac-bc)=a^3-b^3-c^3-3abc$$
Thus $a=b+c$ or $a^2+b^2+c^2+a(b+c)=bc$ I couldn't do anything more.
Is there any other answer?
This question was asked 32 years ago at Iranian Math Competition.

Comment: If $a=b=1$, $c=0$ then $a^3-b^3-c^3 - 3abc = 0$.

Comment: I don't see how you're getting $a=b=c$

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 you're right but this won't satisfy the second equation.

Comment: Yeah I just meant that your deduction is incorrect

Comment: Excuse me because of my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a-b-c=0$ implies $a=b+c$ (and not $a=b=c$). Substitute into the second equation to deduce $a^2=2a$, which yields $a=2$, since we rule out $a=0$. The only positive integer solutions to $2=b+c$ are $b=1$, $c=1$, so one solution to the system is $(a,b,c)=(2,1,1)$.

The second factor $a^2+b^2+c^2 +ab+ac-bc$ is strictly positive for $a,b,c$ positive, since it exceeds $b^2-bc+c^2 > b^2-2bc+c^2=(b-c)^2\ge0$. Therefore there are no other solutions.